# How to get the userid of the user that placed an order inside Magento admin panel?

Tags: magento, admin, enterprise, ecommerce-sales

We are rewarding our admin users by how many orders the help customers with per day. So we would need to track which admins placed which orders, I think the easiest way would be to add admin userid into sales flat order table on magento.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating an [Event-Observer](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method) type module on the `sales_order_save_after` event, just make sure you enclose it in the `<adminhtml>` node instead of `<global>`, otherwise customers placing orders on the front-end of your website could trigger the observer function.

In `Observer.php` you can relate the two by:

1. Calling `$observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getId();` //this fetches the `entity_id` value from the `sales_flat_order` table
2. Relating it to `Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getUserId();` //this fetches the `user_id` value from the `admin_user` table

Alternately, it does look like there is a module already available on MagentoConnect:

[Administrator Who Placed The Order](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/administrator-who-placed-the-order.html)

It is a paid-for extension though, implementing the Event-Observer method seems simple enough.

Comment: +1

Created an observer and added:


class PackageName_Module_Model_Observer {
    public function admin(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $admin = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getEmail();
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getIncrementId();
        Mage::log('Order id = '.$order. ' - Admin is: '.$admin,null,'whichadmin.log');
    } 
}